# Is Ubuntu 21.04 compatible with PHP sqlsrv driver?

Tags: php, sql-server, ubuntu, pdo

I have a web system developed with PHP + MS Sql Server and I do maintenance on Windows environment. But I prefer working in Linux environment, Ubuntu to be more accurate.

But I cannot find a way to install this database driver. I googled but I cannot find any solution. Some tutorials shows how to install in 20.04, 18.04 versions, but even following the steps to the letter, I could no install.

Some tutorials that did not worked.

- [How to Install the PHP SQLSRV Extension](https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-install-the-php-sqlsrv-extension/)
- [Linux and macOS Installation Tutorial for the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain in greater detail why you can’t install it? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Have you tried following their instructions? Did you `s/16.04|18.04|20.04|20.10/21.04/` the sources URLs they mentioned?

Comment: Based on Microsoft's documentation it is not compatible. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15#installing-on-ubuntu says "Ubuntu versions 16.04, 18.04, and 20.04 are supported.".

Answer (score 1):

It seems, at least today, that `msodbcsql17` `mssql-tools` are not available in the Ubuntu 21.04 repos...

```
$ curl -s https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/21.04/prod.list
deb [arch=amd64,armhf,arm64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/21.04/prod hirsute main
```

```
$ curl -s https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/21.04/prod/dists/hirsute/Contents-amd64.gz | gzip -d | grep -E "msodbcsql|mssql"
# No output.
```

As a result you'll get errors when you try to install them via `apt-get`:

```
$ curl -s https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -

$ sudo bash -c "curl -s https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/21.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list"

$ sudo apt-get update --yes
# ...

$ sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get --verbose-versions --yes install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package msodbcsql17
E: Unable to locate package mssql-tools
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**
I have written a bash script to automatically install the appropriate drivers for Ubuntu or Debian: https://github.com/sfinktah/bash/blob/master/add_sqlsrv_repo_combined.sh

I couldn't test support for other Linux vendors, but the capability is there if someone wants to send a PR.

**Original Post**

## 21.04 drivers are now available.

Follow the instructions on

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#ubuntu17

Or as above:

```sh
sudo su
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

#Download appropriate package for the OS version
#Choose only ONE of the following, corresponding to your OS version

# Automatic version selection (does not work for 21.10, but 20.10 or 21.04 are fine)
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -r -s)/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

# Manual specification: Ubuntu 21.04
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/21.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list


sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17
# optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
# optional: for unixODBC development headers
sudo apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
```